# Simple login script isnt working correctly

Tags: php, sql, authentication, pdo

Ive created a simple login script which works to an extent. All the validation is working correctly so if i enter the wrong username and password it shows me the error message Your username or password is wrong but when i enter the correct username and password it doesnt direct me to the users/index.php page and sort of just reloads the login page.

Here is my code -

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $errors = []; 

    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;

    if(!empty($_POST)) {
    if(empty($username)) {
        $errors[] = "Please enter a username"; 
        echo "<style type=\"text/css\"> #username { background-color:#F5A9A9;border:1px solid #DF0101; } </style>";
    }
    if(empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = "Please enter a password"; 
        echo "<style type=\"text/css\"> #password { background-color:#F5A9A9;border:1px solid #DF0101; } </style>";
    } else {

    if(empty($errors)) {
        $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=uacvideos;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', '');
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        if(!$connect) {
                header("Location:"); // ADD ERROR LINK
            }

        $salt = "Thisismysalt";
        $hashedpass = hash('sha512', $password . $salt);

        $result = $connect->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$hashedpass'");
            if($result->fetchColumn() > 0) {
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'true';
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                    header("Location: users/index.php"); // ADD LINK
                } else {
                    $errors[] = "Your username or password is incorrect"; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't `$errors = [];` provokes an fatal error?

Comment: @S.Pols it won't as it is like assigning string value to an array of strings

Comment: Add `exit;` after `header("Location: users/index.php");` And also comment out this `header("Location:"); // ADD ERROR LINK` and echo something there.

Comment: @S.Pols It's actually shorthand array since 5.4: https://eval.in/229328 - [See docs](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) ;)

Comment: lolka_bolka, i what you said but still doesnt direct me to the users/index.php page

Answer (score 0):

You have to use echo to make the error display
sample code :

```
echo $errors[] = "Please enter a username";
```